# template image not showing with media url in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my template i have done:

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{file.media_file}}"
```

When I do inspect emlement i get

```
<img width="100" height="100" src="/media/sta.jpg"></img>
```

sta.jpt file is in my media folder but it says `could not load image`

What is wrong in here ?

Comment: More information, please. Are you running the debug server? What is the value of your `MEDIA_ROOT`? Have you setup the server ([debug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) or [otherwise](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/deployment/)) to serve your media files?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 'django.template.context_processors.media' to your 'context_processors' option of TEMPLATES. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#media-url